# The exercise 15.41 in book of c++ primer 4th

Tags: c++, class, constructor

```
class Query{
    friend Query operator&(const Query&,const Query&);
    friend Query operator|(const Query&,const Query&);
    friend Query operator~(const Query&);
public:
    Query(const string&);           //build a new WordQuery ??
    Query(const Query&c):p(c.p),use(c.use){++*use;}
    ~Query(){delQuery();}
    Query operator=(const Query&c);
    set<TextQuery::line_no> eval(const TextQuery&c) const{return p->eval(c);}
    ostream& display(ostream&s) const {return p->display(s);}
private:
    Query(QueryBase *query):p(query),use(new size_t(1)){}
    QueryBase *p;
    size_t* use;
    void delQuery(){
        if(--*use==0)
            delete p;
            delete use;
    }
};

class WordQuery:public QueryBase{
    friend class Query;
    WordQuery(const string& s):QueryWord(s){}  //Query use the WordQuery constructor
    set<lineno> eval(const TextQuery&t) const
    {return t.run_query(QueryWord);}
    ostream& display(ostream& os) const
    {return os<<QueryWord;}
    string QueryWord;
};
```

I invoke it in expression `Query q=Query(s1) & Query(s2) | Query(s3);`

```
ERRORS:"TextQueryADVANCE.cpp:(.text+0x15ba): undefined reference to `Query::Query(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
"
```

Comment: When asking questions, please 1) remember to put in the actual **question**, not just a listing of source code and an error message, and 2) **format your code** so we can read it. It isn't difficult to select the text, and click the `101010` button, and it makes the difference between "random garbage" and "readable source code" for us. It also gives the impression that you *care* about getting your question answered. If you can't even be bothered to formulate a readable question, why should anyone else be bothered to answer it?

Comment: There is a very convenient preview window below the edit-box when you write a question. You can see if your formatting is good there instantly.

Comment: please give a description of the question since not everyone has that book. Please format your code so that it's readable

Comment: sorry,i am new and my english is not good

Comment: It's not a case of poor English here, its a case or poor code formatting and a lack of English for us to read in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you put the prototype for the constructor, but you didn't actually put an implementation.

You put: `Query(const string&);`, which says that there is a constructor somewhere that takes a string and creates a Query with it.  However, somewhere you actually have to put something that does that.

Answer (score 2):

This is a linker error. It seems you have not provided an implementation for `Query(const string&)`.

Comment: if you've read the book you can kown this is not the cause

Comment: @liu: If you know what is not cause, write that in your question. Do not expect us to have some book ready and look things up, just to answer your question.

Comment: @liu if you had read the book you would know what the problem is.